# How do i set the value of a dropdown list to a function i have in java script

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

this is the javascript function that I have

```js
function GetUserAddress() {
  var address = '<%= Session["addressmap"].ToString() %>';
  return address;
}
```

I want to set the value for this dropdown list below to whatever address this function returns

```html
<select id="end">
  <option value="" >Select Value</option>
  <option value="GetUserAddress()" ></option>
</select>
```

Comment: HTML select and JS doesn't work this imaginative way. What it the purpose of this unusual ergonomic ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your address variable returns an `Array`, you can do something like this in plain JS to create custom options.
jsfiddle DEMO : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23cs9oz7/)

```
    <select id="end">
      <option value="" >Select Value</option>
      
    </select>
    <script>
    (function() {
        var address = ['USA','Australia'];
        var select = document.getElementById("end");
        for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value", address[i]);
            option.text = address[i];
            select.appendChild(option);
            }
    })();
    </script>
```

This is just to give you an idea of how you can achieve dynamic operations.